# Handling MySQL Timestamp in java

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I'm using Retrofit to connect my android App to a DB and getting JSON Objects like this

```
{
"id":1,
"title":"clean room",
"description":"clean my room",
"isVisible":true,
"status":1,
"createTimestamp": {"date":"2015-05-08 13:44:03.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"},
"updateTimestamp":null,
"user_id":1,"category_id":1
}
```

I also got a Java Class Advert with those Attributes. The createTimestamp is set to a TIMESTAMP in MySQL

```
@SerializedName("createTimestamp")
@Expose
private Timestamp createTimestamp;
```

Java gives me an error, like this:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

If I am creating a new Class TimestampObject with given Attributes timezone_type, date, timezone, .... and set the createTimestamp Attribute in my Advert class to private TimestampObject it works, but i have to convert the date from String to int values to make a new Date or Calender Object. I Also didn't figure out how to use the values timezone_type and timezone. Is there any way to get the JSON Object createTimestamp and save it as an Timestamp in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid it. Primarily because I'm not sure that the Timestamp object can be serialized. Create the TimestampObject you were refering, and go for it.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, could you give me an advise for what i can do with the timezone_type and timezone?

Comment: Sorry, can't. Can't you get it as UNIX Timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Get Date From MySql. Please find below example.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class GetDateFromMySql {
  public static Connection getMySQLConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      conn = getMySQLConnection();
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select timeCol, dateCol, dateTimeCol from dateTimeTable");
      while (rs.next()) {
        java.sql.Time dbSqlTime = rs.getTime(1);
        java.sql.Date dbSqlDate = rs.getDate(2);
        java.sql.Timestamp dbSqlTimestamp = rs.getTimestamp(3);
        System.out.println("dbSqlTime=" + dbSqlTime);
        System.out.println("dbSqlDate=" + dbSqlDate);
        System.out.println("dbSqlTimestamp=" + dbSqlTimestamp);

        java.util.Date dbSqlTimeConverted = new java.util.Date(dbSqlTime.getTime());
        java.util.Date dbSqlDateConverted = new java.util.Date(dbSqlDate.getTime());
        System.out.println("in standard date");
        System.out.println(dbSqlTimeConverted);
        System.out.println(dbSqlDateConverted);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```